# How can I get object key in a json-file with handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

in the following json file:

```
{
  "students":[
  {
    "timestamp": "1,45198E+12",
    "personnummer": 1234567891011,
    "fornavn": "Some name"
  }
 ]
}
```

I'm using handlebars to make a table out of this information, how can I go about geting "timestamp","personnummer" and so forth in to the `<th>` tag.
I have tried :
Index: `{{@index}} Value = {{this}}`
and: Key: `{{@key}} Value = {{this}}`
But I just get: "Index: 0 Value = [object Object]"
Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
var obj = {
  "students":[
  {
    "timestamp": "1,45198E+12",
    "personnummer": 1234567891011,
    "fornavn": "Some name"
  }
 ]
}
```

then your handlebar should look like a loop:

```
   <ul class="student_list">
  {{#each students.[0]}}
    <li>{{@key}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vduqnhsb/

Comment: Perhaps i was a little unclear in what i was asking for :) i was looking for a way to get "timestamp" in as table header, not the value of timestamp but the "headline" if you will :)

Comment: you have = between var and the name of the object

Comment: var obj = {
  "students":[
  {
    "timestamp": "1,45198E+12",
    "personnummer": 24534234221 } ] } (Json allows only one top level value

Comment: You are correct if I loop thru this i get the value of timestamp, but is there a way to dynamically get the actual "timestamp" in for a table header tag, not the value?

Comment: Thank you so much ;) helped a lot :)